# content disappears when flex item wraps

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider the following simple flex-box design:

```css
#a {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.b {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div class="b">
    Hello1
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    Hello2
  </div>
</div>
```

When the window's width shrinks below ~400px the right div containing "Hello2" jumps below the other one. This is exactly the behavior I'm aiming at.

However, if Hello1 is replaced by really long content, the mechanism does not work anymore. Instead the other div disappears completely.

Does anybody know, how to fix this? See this fiddle for a complete sample:

UPDATE:

Here's an updated fiddle that should make the problem more transparent: https://jsfiddle.net/yrLjbhmx/7/

Comment: In your JSFiddle, I see the second box getting pushed underneath the first box just as you described. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the issue?

Comment: i think it's best described like this: Replace the many hellos in the fiddle with just a short text and see the resizing behavior. I'd like to see the same with the long text, just that the overflowing disappears. In other words: the text from the second inner div should always be visible..

Comment: @AntonHarald so you want the boxes to be a certain height?

Comment: yes, the container should never grow...

Comment: @AntonHarald maybe you can add custom scrolling or hidden overflow-y for the 1st div hello 1 but you need a max-height also for the class .b or the 1st div

Comment: @AntonHarald [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/4oL19fyf/2/ ] maybe you're looking something like this as you mention container should never grow.

Answer (score 4):

1st Tricks: Just replace the min-width to max-width in class b

```css
#a {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.b {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*jsut add this for better view*/
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div class="b">
Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1
Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1
Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1
Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1
Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1
  </div>
  <div class="b">
Hello2
  </div>
</div>
```

2nd Tricks:use nth:child for make this don't know is it helpful for you or not. I also comment out on css where I changes and why. Now if the screen shrink ~400px the hello 2 won't  disappears( tested on screen size width 389px and height 240px ) [LiveOnFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/yjco6u1a/2/)

```css
#a {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.b {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*jsut add this for better view*/
}

div.b:nth-child(1) {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /*you can set hidden also*/
  height: 200px;
  /*you can set this on .b class*/
  border: 1px solid green;
  /*jsut add this for better view*/
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div class="b">
Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1
Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1
Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1
Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1
Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello1
  </div>
  <div class="b">
Hello2
  </div>
</div>
```